# How to check mysql db for an entry with less code

Tags: c#, mysql, performance

Hi i want to know if there is a more simplified method than the one im using now to find if there is an entry or not in a mysql db.

```
public static bool check_db_entry(string query)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(DbMethods.constr))
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.Read() == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you start a new connection every time you call this function? Performance is going to be horrible.

Comment: @Trent that's the right way to do it. Connections in .Net are pooled, so this is actually fairly efficient.

Comment: For a start, you can do: `return rdr.Read()`

Comment: What is really bad here is that the method signature practically forces you into writing code that is horribly insecure. If it's your main data access pattern, you're practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: This function can run about once every 2-3 secs but other queries are being executed too, should i have an open connection for all the queries?

Comment: @Incognito No, you should not. But if this runs on it's own in the background, you might want to keep one specifically reserved for this process.

Comment: @Simon Belanger: Totally didnt see that thanks. 
&at Joel Coehoorn: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Cheers mate; never really worked in .NET, and just brought along my other language ideology (incorrectly). Now I know, gotta love SO

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: This program will run locally and it wont have external access on the db.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Lots of hacks are inside jobs. If there wasn't db access at some level, the method wouldn't be asking for an sql string. If you have a method, any method, that accepts an sql string as an argument with intent to execute that sql, it **must** also ask parameter data separate from the string. No exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside for now that fact that methods that accept only sql strings are inherently unsafe, this smells wrong to me. If you're going to have public methods that accept arbitrary sql commands (remember: I said "If"), then undoubtedly you have one that returns the data directly. You should rely on that as your base. Here's an example:

```
private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetDataImpl(string query)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(DbMethods.constr))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           yield return rdr;
        }
    }
}

public static bool check_db_entry(string query)
{
    return GetDataImpl(query).Any();
}
```

Note there is a reason I listed the first method as private. As written, it can have weird side effects if you don't first copy each element in the reader before returning it to a higher abstraction level in your program. But you can get the public version easily enough:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string query, Func<IDataRecord,T> copy)
{
    return GetDataImpl(query).Select(copy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking aside your design issues pointed in the question's comments, if you want to check the existence an entry in the database, you should always query with `COUNT(*)`: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable [WHERE theCondition]`.

If that is all you pass to your function, you can then simply with:

```
public static bool check_db_entry(string query)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(DbMethods.constr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to streamline it:

```
public static bool check_db_entry(string query)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(DbMethods.constr))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
    }
}
```